# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null occurs after second call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to place the value of my auto compute age function in a dynamic textbox. It's being triggered by onchange of datepicker.

It's working the first time I call it (because the first textbox is static) but when I try to call it after that, it just returns null.

I have 3 files for this:

1. **header.php**
   `<script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>`
2. **dependents.php**

   ```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <label for="num_dependents" class="text-left">Dependents:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="pull-right">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addRow">
                           Add <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                       </button>
                   </div>
                   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dependent_table">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th style="width:45%;">Name of Dependent</th>
                               <th style="width:10%;">Age</th>
                               <th style="width:35%;">Date of Birth</th>
                               <th style="width:10%;"></th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr>
                               <td class="vert-align"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_dependent_1" id="name_dependent_1"></td>
                               <td class="vert-align"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="age_dependent_1" id="age_dependent_1" disabled></td>
                               <td class="vert-align">
                                   <div class="col-md-12">
                                       <div class="form-group has-feedback" style="margin-top:12px;">
                                           <input class="form-control datePick" id="dob_dependent_1" name="dob_dependent_1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text" onchange="CalculateAge(this.value, 'age_dependent_1');"/>
                                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></i>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </td>
                               <td></td>
                           </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. **functions.js**

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).delegate('#addRow', 'click', AddRow);

    var i = 1;
    var id_age;
    function AddRow() {
       i++;
       id_age = 'age_dependent_'+ i;
       $("#dependent_table").append( "<tr>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:45%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name_dependent_" + i + "' id='name_dependent_" + i + "'></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='age_dependent_"+ i +"' id=\"'"+id_age+"'\" disabled></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:35%;'><div class='col-md-12'><div class='form-group has-feedback' style='margin-top:12px;'><input class='form-control datePick' id='dob_dependent_"+ i +"' name='dob_dependent_"+ i +"' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' type='text' onchange=\"CalculateAge(this.value,'" + id_age + " ');\"/><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></i></div></div></td>"+ "<td class='vert-align' style='width:10%;'><img src='images/disk.png' class='btnSave'><img src='images/delete.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+ "</tr>"); 

       $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);  
       $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
       return false
    }
   });


   var date_val;
   function CalculateAge(date_val, id_age){
     var today = new Date(), 
         dob = new Date(date_val), 
         age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;
     document.getElementById(id_age).value = age;
     //return $('#'+id_age).val(age);
   }
   ```

You can see it in action [here](http://polomemorialpark.com/online_services.php). Click the Login tab on the left side then click Signup. On Civil Status you can click any option except for "Single" then the Dependents Section will show up. You can try inputting date by datepicker and you can see the age go to the disabled textbox beside it. When you click 'Add Row' and do it again that's where the error occurs.

I hope someone could help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your developer's console you will see that after you select some date in datepicker this error happens:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>
> `document.getElementById(id_age).value = age;`

What does this means? That `id_age` value is something that is not present on your page.

Let's check your `CalculateAge` function: so it takes some value and id of an element. For the second input this `id` should be `'age_dependent_2'`, right?

So, let's find it in your page!
After some searching I can definitely tell that there's no element with such id on your page. But! I see this:

```
<input id="'age_dependent_2'"
```

See? You got extra quotes and they ruin everything. Let's find - where they came from. It's definitely `AddRow` function and it is here:

```
id=\"'"+id_age+"'\"
```

See - you add extra quote here. So remove them - just

```
id='"+id_age+"'
```

And second bug - you have extra space in function's arguments:

```
CalculateAge(this.value,'" + id_age + " ')
//                                     ^ this is it
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. I changed that now but it's still returning null. `document.getElementById(id_age).value = age;`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The last one did it: 

`CalculateAge(this.value,'" + id_age + " ')`

That simple space really ruined it. You're a lifesaver! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use moment.js for any type of Date manipulation, is precise and easier. 
Also, I'm not sure if this.value is a good idea when calling your function, you can instead just do `$("#dob_dependent_1").val()` to get the value of the input in your function, you can even put an alert() or a console.log() in your code to make sure you're getting the right value.

Comment: I can get both the value of the age and the value of the id right. I just can't get it to show since it's returning null. The textboxes are dynamic so the id values change. It also works when I replace `document.getElementById(id_age).value = age;` with `$('#'+id_age).val(age);`, but same result, it returns null after the first call.